# Problem with System`Graph and Combinatorica`Graph functionality conflict

Tags: functions, graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to generate a random geometric graph. When evaluating `HighlightGraph`, even if I am passing graph object *Mathematica* always gives error like

> A graph object is expected at position 1 in  RowBox[{"HighlightGraph", "[", RowBox[{InterpretationBox[StyleBox[RowBox[{...`

How can I solve this problem. I am new to *Mathematica* programming and am using *Mathematica* 9. my code is..

```
v = {};
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, v = Append[v, {{Random[], Random[]}}]];
g = Graph[{}, v];
keyrings = {};
        For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
            keyring = {};
            If[P == K, 
                For[k = 1, Length[keyring] < K, k++,
                        keyring = Append[keyring, k]
                    ],
                (* P > K *)
                For[k = 1, Length[keyring] < K, k++,
                        key = Random[Integer, {1, P}];
                        If[MemberQ[keyring, key] == False,
                            keyring = Append[keyring, key]
                        ]
                    ]
            ];
            keyrings = Append[keyrings, keyring];
        ];
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
            For[j = i + 1, j <= n, j++, 
                xi = Extract[Extract[Extract[v, i], 1], 1];
                xj = Extract[Extract[Extract[v, j], 1], 1];
                yi = Extract[Extract[Extract[v, i], 1], 2];
                yj = Extract[Extract[Extract[v, j], 1], 2];
                If[dist[xi, yi, xj, yj][[1]] < rc, 
                        If[
     Extract[keyrings, {i}] ⋂ 
       Extract[keyrings, {j}] != {},
                            g = AddEdge[g, {{i, j}}],
                            (* Else *)
                            Print["No secure link between ", i, " ", j]
                        ]
                    ]
            ]
        ];
HighlightGraph[g, {NeighborhoodGraph[g, 1], Labeled[1, 1]}];
Print[ShowGraph[g]]
]
]
```

Please tell me where I have made a mistake.

Comment: Built in Mathematica functions and `Combinatorica\`` functions consider different things to be `Graph`'s. Related: [Use of MinimumSpanningTree](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18687/4330)

Comment: @user11609 it would be helpful to give a small example to work out where the problem arises

Comment: @m_goldberg I am confused about your opinion on [Backquotes in titles](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/993/4330). By the way, do you know how (if that is possible) to add "comments" (invisible text) to a queston/answer (maybe using html)? In the linked Q&A I would want to add the word backtick as a comment for search purposes.

Comment: @ubpdqn....i have edited the question and written the code..plz see

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom. I think this is a case where back ticks are OK.

Comment: @m_goldberg agreed :). Please see my edit to my comment also

Answer (score 1):

Don't use *Combinatorica*. It's been obsolete since Version 8. Take a look at [`RandomGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RandomGraph.html). With that you should be to get what you want. For example,

```
HighlightGraph[RandomGraph[{5, 6}], {1 -> 3}]
```

[image: randgraph]

#### Note

When one loads *Combinatorica* in V8 or later, one gets the message

> General::compat: Combinatorica Graph and Permutations functionality has been superseded by preloaded functionality. The package now being loaded may conflict with this. Please see the Compatibility Guide for details.

Comment: i used this but giving error every time as mentioned in the question..i've inclued the code too..plz see

Comment: i've removed combinatorica still did not get the output

Comment: Ah, I suspected it might be, but I never saw this statement. If it is true that it is (fully?) obsolete, then this should get many upvotes :).

Comment: @user11609. Did you start a fresh _Mathematica_ session to get rid of _Combinatorica_? As look as it's loaded, you will have problems.

Comment: yeah i did that too but still didn't get output....i'm trying this last three days and got nothing till now,,

Comment: after removing Combinatorica `ShowGraph` is also not executing.. Instead of using HighlightGraph if i use `GraphHighlight` then error removed from program but still didn't get the highlighted graph...whats the problem?? and here i haven't used inbuilt random graph of mathematica..

Comment: ShowGraph, AddEdge are Combinatorica function and also code you are running need to load Combinatorica. You better use other code to generate graph like one in the answer of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38589/random-geometric-graph-generation-problem

Comment: @halmir..in the given link, code with System graph functionality i am unable put HighlightGraph function, plz help a little more by telling where should i change in order to get highlighted adjacent edges from any given vertex.

Comment: @user11609 which code did you try? if you set g = RandomKeyGeoGraph[...]; then HighlightGraph[g, ..] should work.

Comment: From [Compatibility/tutorial/Combinatorica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compatibility/tutorial/Combinatorica.html), we have "As of Version 8, much of the functionality covered by Combinatorica has been implemented in the Mathematica kernel." But I think probably not all functionality.